# SharePoint 2010 with Always-On SQL Server 2012 cluster

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am setting up a SharePoint 2010 on SQL 2012, and planning to use SQL 2012 Always-On cluster.

The cluster is established with 3 nodes with standard installs of SQL 2012 using AD accounts for services.

Whilst the cluster is running, I am unsure what to do with the SQL Server Analysis Services.

Currently I have two reporting service instances of SQL:

Default instance - Multidimensional and Data Mining analysis mode
Tabular instance - Tabular analysis mode

Do I need to cluster the above services, and if so how do I go about this?

Appreciate any direction that can be given.

In case needed, I am referencing [this post](http://blog.cloudshare.com/2012/05/22/step-by-step-guide-to-installing-sharepoint-with-sql-2012-powerpivot-powerview-and-reporting-services/).

Comment: I've never heard of clustered Analysis Services, so my instinct would be... no, you probably don't.  Then again, maybe you could see about having this migrated to the dba stack exchange site, where you're more likely to find a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge SSAS does not have an AlwaysOn equivalent.  What you can do is set up an identical instance and replicate the SSAS data using an OLAP replicate task called from a SQL agent job on your clustered SQL instance.

Once that is in place you can set up a DNS alias that points to the main copy of the cube, then re-point the alias over to the replicated cube.  The failover is manual but I don't know of a better way for a hot-hot set SSAS setup.

Comment: that makes sense, alternatively I think analysis services supports traditional active/passive failover as used in sql 2008 and before which is still available in sql 2012. That makes a clean separation and could even just install analysis services on a machine outside of the cluster should this be needed - as far as I can tell SharePoint powers pivot runs on a SharePoint server and is not reliant on the sql analysis services of a seperate server

Comment: SSAS is absolutely supported as an active/passive setup on a Windows cluster, since SQL 2005.  Powerpivot is installed on one of the SP farm servers, and only relies on external SSAS/SSDS as far as consuming the data for Powerpivot databases.  I think load balancing the Powerpivot instances on the SP layer is done automatically by SP if you have more than one SP server and Powerpivot instance, but I am not totally sure.